# Multiple text box with same name

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

I have multiple text boxes which are created dynamically , these text boxes have the same name different id's. I need to get values of all those text boxes via ajax but did not have any clue, please suggest how can I achieve this.

**Edit**

I had tried

```
$('#addMultipleEducationLevel').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "${createLink(controller: 'someController', action: 'someAction')}",
        data: {degreeId:$( "#degree" ).val(),fieldOfStudy:$('[name=fieldsOfStudy]').serialize()}
    });
})
```

But I am getting

```
 [fieldOfStudy:fieldsOfStudy=&fieldsOfStudy=Biblical+Hebrew&fieldsOfStudy=Applied+Business+(Double+Award), degreeId:3, action:someAction, controller:somecontroller]
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an attribute selector and  `serialize()` to gather the data to send:

```
var ajaxData= $('[name=name]').serialize();

$.post('/path/to/server', ajaxData, function(response){
   /* do something with response */
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BrfLZ/)**</kbd>

Comment: check it for what? You need to be more specific with your issue details as to what your expectations are. That is why you are getting numerous down votes

Answer (score 1):

hi @Abdullah you get all value using this way.

if you have multiple textbox with same name like

```
<input type="text" name="a1" value="a">
<input type="text"  name="a1" value="b">
<input type="text"  name="a1" value="c">
<input type="text" name="a1" value="d">
```

jquery code:

```
var a="";
$("input:text").each(function () {
    if (this.value != undefined) {
        a += this.value +',';
    }       
});
alert(a);
```

and now submit your value with ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "send.aspx?value=" + a,
    type: "get"
}).done(function () {
    alert("Send successfully!!");
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NeerajRai/sWG8s/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Script is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ex input:text').each(function(){
       alert(this.value) 
    });
});
```

Example HTML

```
<div id="ex">
    <input type="text" id="one" name="first" value="10">
    <input type="text" id="two" name="first" value="11">
    <input type="text" id="three" name="first" value="12">
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FbMh3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

To get a textbox value, according to the fact that they have different IDs **try the following jQuery snippet:**

```
$("#ID OF YOUR CHECKBOX").val();
```

**Then if you want to send these values via AJAX, use this snippet:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "receiver.php?value="+your_value_here+"&value2="+anpther_value_here,
}).done(function() {
    alert("data sent");
});
```

Comment: Id's are created dynamicaly

Comment: Then browse all of them with $("input[type=checkbox]").each()